# Getting a warning that a number is too small to be represented as a normalized machine number

Tags: numerics, warning-messages

I have the following summations:

The code:

```
Nmax = 60

ρ = SetPrecision[10/10, 30]

Mmax = 60

c = SetPrecision[1/10000, 30]

G[i_, j_, k_, n_, m_] = 
  E^(-(1/8) 
    ((c π)/ρ)^2 ((n + 1/2)^2 + (m + 1/2)^2 + 
     8 ρ^2 (i^2 + j^2 + k^2)))/(((n + 1/2)^2 + 
     4 ρ^2 (i^2 + j^2 + k^2)) ((m + 1/2)^2 + 
     4 ρ^2 (i^2 + j^2 + k^2))) 
    (2 + Cos[π (n - m)] + Cos[π (n + m + 1)])

H[n_, m_] = 
  (G[0, 0, 0, n, m] + 
   Sum[6*G[i, 0, 0, n, m], {i, 1, +Nmax}] +
   Sum[12*G[i, i, 0, n, m], {i, 1, +Nmax}] + 
   Sum[24*G[i, j, 0, n, m], {i, 1, +Nmax}, {j, 1, i - 1}] +
   Sum[8*G[i, i, i, n, m], {i, 1, +Nmax}] +
   Sum[24*G[i, i, j, n, m], {j, 1, +Nmax}, {i, 1, j - 1}] + 
   Sum[24*G[i, i, j, n, m], {i, 1, +Nmax}, {j, 1, i - 1}] +
   Sum[48*G[i, j, k, n, m], {i, 1, +Nmax}, {j, 1, i - 1}, {k, 1, j - 1}])


Subscript[J, 5] = 
  (Sqrt[2] c^3 ρ^2)/((8 - 5 Sqrt[2]) / (24 π^(5/2))) 
    (H[0, 0] + 2*Sum[H[n, 0] + H[-n, 0], {n, 1, Mmax}] +
     Sum[H[n, n] + 2*H[n, -n] + H[-n, -n], {n, 1, Mmax}] + 
     2*Sum[H[n, m], {n, 1, Mmax}, {m, 1, n - 1}])
```

[image]

The formulae are correct, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

What I get is the following error mex:

> 2.607130362672965*10^-304 0.000071315866888934451803845708122 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

[image]

Could you help me?

Moreover, I used `SetPrecision` in that way because of a suggestion on this forum, it worked in a previous cas. Can you suggest something better?

Comment: Your images show that `c = 0.1`, which is `MachinePrecision`. It does not reflect the code you posted, in which `c = SetPrecision[1/10000, 30]`.

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that you are doing anything wrong.  That warning just indicates that `Exp[-x]` is too small to be represented as a machine sized number. It will be approximated to zero which generally is OK.  You can get around the problem by using exact numbers.  The only inexact number that I see is `c`.  I get no warnings with:

```
Nmax = 60
ρ = 1
Mmax = 60
c = 1/10
```

The rest the same as you have.
Output the numerical answer

```
Subscript[J, 5] // N[#, 30] &
(*119.934233306915048382716902712*)
```

for the `c` that matches your screenshot,

for `c = 1/10000` which matches your code:

```
Subscript[J, 5] // N[#, 30] &
(*3.57168015500528945976180486670*10^-7*)
```

No warnings in this case, but you can see for `c = .1`, both results are pretty much the same.